# Scala: tokenization and dictionary

Tags: scala, dictionary, tokenize

I want to get a numeric identifier for each unique word that occurs in a text.

For that purpose, I've written this function that stores the words in a mutable.Map

```
var dict = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Int]()
var i = 0

def addToDict(line:String) = {
    var words = line.split(' ') //returns String[]
    for(w <- words) {
        if(!(dict.contains(w))) {
            dict.put(w, i)
            i = i+1
        }
    }
}

longtext.collect().foreach(addToDict) //returns the text line by line, where each line contains a few words
```

Is a mutable.Map the best collection for this purpose, or is there a better one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach that relies in zipping with indexes,

```
def addToDict(line: String) = 
  line.split("\\W+").distinct.zipWithIndex.toMap
```

Note `\\W+` splits a line into words.

Hence

```
addToDict("the text line by line")
res: Map(the -> 0, text -> 1, line -> 2, by -> 3)
```

**Update**

For a given text file, consider this,

```
implicit class RichFile(val filename: String) extends AnyVal {

  def toDict() = {
    val words = io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+")).toSeq
    words.distinct.zipWithIndex.toMap
  }

}
```

Use it like this,

```
"longTextFilename".toDict()
```

Comment: Do you mean that groupBy.keys is more efficient than distinct?

Answer (score 2):

A fold would definitely be more idiomatic and you can use `distinct` to consider each word only once:

```
def addToDict(line: String) =
  line.split(' ').distinct.foldLeft((0, Map[String, Int]())){
    case ((i, m), s) => (i + 1, m + (s -> i))
  }._2
```

example

```
addToDict("a few words and another few words")
// Map(a -> 0, few -> 1, words -> 2, and -> 3, another -> 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

For such, mutable struct is not necessary. I would prefer something like:

```scala
def addToDict(line: String): Map[Int, String] =
  line.split(' '). // 1. split words
  foldLeft(0 -> Map.empty[String, Int]) { (st, w) => // 2. will fill the dict
    val (i, m): (Int, Map[String, Int]) = st // current state

    // determine next state...
    if (!m.contains(w)) {
      val j = i+1 // new num id
      j -> (m + (w, j)) // updated state
    } else i -> m // unchanged stated
  }
```

Comment: BTW, in Scala I would say that `var` should not be used if not strictly mandatory (e.g. actors), same for mutable datatype, and that foreach should better used with caution for side-effecting rather than iteration/loop.